# Transit in Heathrow with an Italian student visa

Tags: visas, air-travel, uk, indian-citizens, lhr

I am an Indian citizen travelling from India to Italy on a student visa via the UK. My flight stops at Heathrow for 2.5 hours. Will I be required to have a transit visa?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What is your citizenship?  And where are you coming from?

Comment: @pnuts UK citizenship isn't the only condition to allow TWOV.

Comment: @Gagravarr Close but there is no US or US visa involved though the widget is the same.

Comment: The other question mentions a “Schengen visa”, which might or might not be the same than what the OP has.

Comment: The answer is given in the thread Karlson references: it's an easy question to look up from https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa .

Comment: @choster Which, again, does not make it a duplicate as it's not the same question and the actual answer *is* different. When you think about it, the questions have very little in common, the citizenship of the person is not the same, the situation is not the same and the visa requirement is not the same (incidentally, the distinction between both situations is subtle and might not be that trivial to understand).

Answer (score 4):

Indian citizens generally [do need a visa for airside transit at Heathrow](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no) but you are probably exempt from this requirement based on your Italian visa. Specifically, you are exempt if you:

> have a valid uniform format category D visa for entry to a state in the European Economic Area (EEA)

An Italian student visa valid for more than three months would be a category D visa (whereas a short-stay Schengen visa would not). If I am not mistaken, it should look approximately like this:

[image]